# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: in AngularJS Service Test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-service

I am having a lot of trouble getting dependencies provided properly for an AngularJS service.

I see a number of other posts with similar errors here on StackOverflow but none of them seem to resolve the issue.

Here is the app code:

```
cm.modules.app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
myServiceName = function($http) {
    // do stuff
};
myServiceName.prototype.value = 1;

cm.modules.app.service('defaultAlertFactoryA', myServiceName);
```

Here is the test code:

```
describe('test alertFactoryA', function() {
  var $provide;
  var mAlertFactoryA;

  beforeEach(module(cm.modules.app));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function(_$provide_) {
    $provide = _$provide_;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function($injector) {
      mAlertFactoryA = $injector.get('defaultAlertFactoryA');
    });
  });

  it('should work', function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Here is the error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: defaultAlertFactoryAProvider
>   <- defaultAlertFactoryA
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/unpr?p0=defaultAlertFactoryAProvider%20%3C-%20defaultAlertFactoryA

Question: How do I fix this so the test passes?

Comment: Is your service file included in your karma config file? (I'm assuming you're using karma)

Comment: @dcodesmith I am using Karma... yes; to check I did console.log(myServiceName); from within the test and it resolved the reference fine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following is what I used to get it working (finally)

```
 beforeEach(function() {
    module(cm.modules.app.name);

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.service('defaultAlertFactoryA', myServiceName);
    });

    inject(function($injector) {
      defaultAlertFactory = $injector.get('defaultAlertFactoryA');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 26):

In order to bootstrap your module you need to provide its name

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/enGEp/)**

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you need to include the service files in your karma.conf.js file

```
files: [

  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'app/app.js',
  'app/controllers/*.js',
  'app/services/*.js',
  'tests/**/*.js'
],
```

If the are not included here they can't be accessed in the unit tests

Comment: If you're using newer versions of webpack, make sure you're not running webpack in production mode otherwise it will uglify the angular sources in the bundle and you'll get this error in your test runs